# How can I output a certain number of observations satisfying a where statement in SAS

Tags: sas

For example I want to output only the first 5 observations in the table CARS which satisfies the WHERE statement that Horsepower is greater than 265.

```
DATA test(obs=5);
SET SASHELP.CARS;
WHERE Horsepower > 265;
RUN;
```

The above doesn't work. This seems very simple but I'm not sure how to achieve what I want here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if(_N_ > 5) then stop`.

```
data want;
    set sashelp.cars;
    where horsepower > 265;
    if(_N_ > 5) then stop;
run;
```

Or, use SQL `outobs`

```
proc sql outobs=5;
    create table want as
        select *
        from sashelp.cars
        where horsepower > 265
    ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
proc print data=SASHELP.CARS(where=(Horsepower>265) obs=10);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to do it. Here are another 2 ways not shown by others:

```
data Want;
    set sashelp.cars;
    where horsepower > 265;
    if _N_ <= 5 then output;
run;

data Want;
    set sashelp.cars (obs=5);
    where horsepower > 265;
run;
```

Comment: Hi, I think your first suggestion may be OK, but doesn't the second one only read the first five records from the input dataset, whether or not they meet the condition?

Comment: They both have the same output. If I understand how this works correctly (and I wouldn't exactly bet my life savings on it), the first one read every instance in which a where condition is satisfied, and then output only the first five. The second one read only first five lines that meet the condition, and output them all.